# TLS and Alert 21 after Handshake

Tags: tls, alert

We have a client/server running TLS v1.0 and keep getting the Encryption Alert 21 from the client after the initial handshake. They are using cipher block chaining and I've read where the block cipher input length being different than something other than a multiple of the block length would cause the Decryption Failed alert but how\where would I find these values to determine if that's the real cause for the alert?

I've attached the handshake sequence below...Thanks...Appreciate it

## Secure Sockets Layer

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello ##
    Content Type: Handshake (22)###
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 254
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 250
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Random
            GMT Unix Time: Jun 25, 1983 13:56:23.000000000 Eastern Daylight Time
            Random Bytes: 2761896c45978dc3868cd4858d7a3d5749f7218e40f5fd3f...
        Session ID Length: 0
        Cipher Suites Length: 100
        Cipher Suites (50 suites)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
        Compression Methods (1 method)
        Extensions Length: 109
        Extension: ec_point_formats
        Extension: elliptic_curves
        Extension: SessionTicket TLS
        Extension: signature_algorithms
        Extension: Heartbeat
```

## Secure Sockets Layer

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Multiple Handshake Messages
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 1449
    Handshake Protocol: Server Hello
        Handshake Type: Server Hello (2)
        Length: 77
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Random
        Session ID Length: 32
        Session ID: 569d341d4d75bc12b41fa995f22fea93a51d14fa1d612e69...
        Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
        Compression Method: null (0)
        Extensions Length: 5
        Extension: renegotiation_info
    Handshake Protocol: Certificate
        Handshake Type: Certificate (11)
        Length: 816
        Certificates Length: 813
        Certificates (813 bytes)
    Handshake Protocol: Server Key Exchange
        Handshake Type: Server Key Exchange (12)
        Length: 540
        Diffie-Hellman Server Params
            p Length: 128
            p: fd7f53811d75122952df4a9c2eece4e7f611b7523cef4400...
            g Length: 20
            g: 9760508f15230bccb292b982a2eb840bf0581cf5
            Pubkey Length: 128
            Pubkey: 73f35da13f584ccb05901f5242f71da41b5f35cc185409a9...
            Signature Length: 256
            Signature: 3b8a31d223c149fb0af62f653be5d61af1297c11c4d6e925...
    Handshake Protocol: Server Hello Done
        Handshake Type: Server Hello Done (14)
        Length: 0
```

## Secure Sockets Layer

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Key Exchange
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 134
    Handshake Protocol: Client Key Exchange
        Handshake Type: Client Key Exchange (16)
        Length: 130
        Diffie-Hellman Client Params
            Pubkey Length: 128
            Pubkey: 76ef1851a1202c19b55aebc2cf830cbb023f15f75d7c963a...
TLSv1 Record Layer: Change Cipher Spec Protocol: Change Cipher Spec
    Content Type: Change Cipher Spec (20)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 1
    Change Cipher Spec Message
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 48
    Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message
```

## Secure Sockets Layer

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Change Cipher Spec Protocol: Change Cipher Spec
    Content Type: Change Cipher Spec (20)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 1
    Change Cipher Spec Message
```

## Secure Sockets Layer

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 48
    Handshake Protocol: Encrypted Handshake Message
```

## Secure Sockets Layer

## client->server

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol: http
    Content Type: Application Data (23)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 32
    Encrypted Application Data: 50c0d7383385d5ea8aa08c9a489904b20fb508a1b53ec017...
TLSv1 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol: http
    Content Type: Application Data (23)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 480
    Encrypted Application Data: 18ad9fa298268b2da260c4873075d8116554d3067659a0f6...
```

## Secure Sockets Layer

## server->client

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol: http
    Content Type: Application Data (23)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 352
    Encrypted Application Data: a425edb24ceb1fab0516b7cf64e18d571db0f222e606d1a7...
```

## Secure Sockets Layer

## client->server

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol: http
    Content Type: Application Data (23)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 32
    Encrypted Application Data: 4952a32d5ca081870f74397b4b45d8af9017938b92db648a...
TLSv1 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol: http
    Content Type: Application Data (23)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 480
    Encrypted Application Data: 3a97d944ddabc997a965cc75ed946aa0dd4b13e525f44aff...
```

## Secure Sockets Layer

## server->client

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol: http
    Content Type: Application Data (23)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 32
    Encrypted Application Data: 47f3838b409d33cfd039f51e432e7675095f6f724ba7c728...
TLSv1 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol: http
    Content Type: Application Data (23)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 352
    Encrypted Application Data: 8bd4f772427b1bf25901b3cc59cff003d83b02bd11421e62...
```

## Secure Sockets Layer

## client->server

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol: http
    Content Type: Application Data (23)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 32
    Encrypted Application Data: 1a0750299f160c207a88d6d6b2bc794373b7d45ae845129f...
TLSv1 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol: http
    Content Type: Application Data (23)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 480
    Encrypted Application Data: 094956aa5f580d500d9402bc84696748f6c008d8f75bcafc...
```

## Secure Sockets Layer

## client->server

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Encrypted Alert
    Content Type: Alert (21)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 32
    Alert Message: Encrypted Alert
```

Comment: villican - please don't add edits that do nothing to help.

Comment: You do understand that `TLS v1.0` is basically broken right?  Is there a reason your client thinks its 1983?

Comment: @Ramhound: The TLS 1.0 standard was first released in 1999.

Comment: @bwDraco - **I actually know that................**  You entirely missed the point of that second unrelated question.  `GMT Unix Time: Jun 25, 1983 13:56:23.000000000 Eastern Daylight Time` hence my question why the client thinks its Junt 25 1983 @ 1:53PM GMT the same of this post.  The time is correct ( or close enough ) but the date is not correct.  Its currently 14:39PM GMT, hence, how I know its close enough.

Comment: 21 is not the alert number, and this is not an "encryption alert". [21 is the record type of *all* alert records](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-6.2) but the alert record is encrypted and Wireshark can't decrypt it so it displays "Encrypted Alert". It *might be* a normal close_notify, but check the server logs to find out if it thinks there was an error and if so what.

Comment: Correction: on rereading I see it's the client that's alerting, so check *client* logs

Answer (score 13):

## It's a Mixup

This is NOT `AlertDescription` 21.

Instead this is [`ContentType` 21](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-A.1).

```
  enum {
      change_cipher_spec(20), alert(21), handshake(22),
      application_data(23), (255)
  } ContentType;
```

What now? So we know that it IS an alert, but, okay what kind? An [`AlertDescription` field is one byte wide](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-A.3). So which one is this? And, sadly, the answer is...

```
Alert Message: Encrypted Alert
```

...we just don't know. It's encrypted.

Q: But won't we be able to just decrypt this packet dump if we use the private key for the certificate?
A: No. This connection used an ephemeral cipher suite (namely `Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)`) so it's [forward secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) and the session bulk encryption key can not be reconstructed from the certificate's private key.

#### Take a new trace.

Take another trace but this time make sure that you can decrypt it afterwards. In order to do that, either have the private key ready and force a non-forward-secure suite (anything without `DHE` or `ECDHE` in the name) or have your software dump the session key somewhere. ([Chrome and Firefox can do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243842/how-to-reach-used-cipher-key-of-current-ssl-connection-under-firefox))

Comment: For Wireshark to decrypt using server key you need suite **without DH** (including ECDH). Strictly speaking only DHE and ECDHE (and EC/DH_anon, rarely used) are *ephemeral*, and DH and ECDH _could_ be decrypted with server key, but Wireshark doesn't do so. (And doing it yourself is a lot of work, although I have on occasion done a frame or two manually.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks. I've got no idea why I wrote "EC".

Answer (score 5):

> ... we have a client/server running TLS v1.0 and keep getting the Encryption Alert 21 from the client after the initial handshake...

It appears the client is down level and it needs to be upgraded.

According to [RFC 5246, The Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol Version 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246), [alert 21 is decryption_failed_RESERVED](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2). And the meaning of the alert:

> decryption_failed_RESERVED
>    This alert was used in some earlier versions of TLS, and may have
>    permitted certain attacks against the CBC mode [CBCATT].  It MUST
>    NOT be sent by compliant implementations.

Comment: The alert number is not known to be 21 and probably isn't; see my comment on the question. Notice the client is apparently doing 1/N-1 fragmentation which was widely implemented in response to BEAST putting it after late 2011. Note that merging alerts 20=MAC and 21='decrypt'=CBC to block the explicit oracle was already recommended in 1.1 in 2009, and that was after many had defacto implemented it in 1.0.